# Drift Correction update of Project Tango after Google IO

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango, googleio

I am looking for the **drift correction update** for the project tango APIs after the presentation on the Google IO 2016. You can find the video at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTZZCtmR3OY). The drift correction update is presented about 22:00 min. I hoped this function would be available after the big Okul update on June 9th, but I can't find it in any API. Does anyone one when this function will be available?

The screenshot below shows what I'm looking for. The **KEY_BOOLEAN_ENABLE_DRIFT_CORRECTION** isn't available in any of the APIs.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm working with Java and Android Studio, but I would also be happy if this new function will be available in C or Unity API.

Comment: hi Konsti, the flag will be available in next (Q) release.

Comment: Hi Jason, that sounds good. Can you estimate a date? I have to finish my master's thesis until August and don't know if I should wait for the update, because I want to finish my development in the next days.

Comment: There's a chance that you could get it, Q is under testing now, and goes out right after that. Anyway, this would be just two line change with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the Q release both my Tango devkit and the Unity package, and looks like it's still in a limbo state on the c# side

As you can see [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Core/Scripts/TangoWrappers)
TangoConfig.cs is the same version as last release, so there is no

```
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION, true)
```

variable to use.

However TangoApplication.cs has been updated in the Q release, as you can see on Line 1149

```
 areaDescription.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION;
```

which does correspond to that example.

The empty man page for [TangoConfig](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=TangoConfig) doesn't help either (I know, still in beta.).

Despite the lack of documentation, I read the TangoConfig class under

Assets/TangoSDK/Core/Scripts/TangoWrappers/TangoConfig.cs

and brutally added

```
public static readonly string ENABLE_DRIFT_CORRECTION_BOOL = "config_enable_drift_correction";
```

on line 365.
Also commented lines 292,293,294,310 so the call would actually pass to the helper.

I also tried adding

```
SetBool (Keys.ENABLE_DRIFT_CORRECTION_BOOL, true);
```

on line 65,and opened the Augmented Reality test scene. It didn't crash, but the coordinate values were not shifted from 0,0,0 to an external origin, as my understanding of drift correction would think.
Another bad telltale sign is that it still crashes if I shake it, and there is no trace of LQ21 (my app name) in the crash log.

Comment: In the Java API there is already the drift correction function, but you can't use it with area learning and loaded area description files. So I haven't tried it out yet, because it's useless for me then.