# KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION crashes on Tango device (Qianru)

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

Since the Google IO I waited for the presented **drift correction** update (look at my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783252/drift-correction-update-of-project-tango-after-google-io)). Now after the **Qianru** update this function is finally available at the Java API. But when trying to use it, the example I try with always **crashes** (Java Floorplan Example). I just added one line (KEY_ENABLE_DRIFT_CORRECTION). Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
        // Use default configuration for Tango Service, plus low latency
    // IMU integration and area learning.
    TangoConfig config = mTango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    // NOTE: Low latency integration is necessary to achieve a precise alignment of virtual
    // objects with the RBG image and produce a good AR effect.
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LOWLATENCYIMUINTEGRATION, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION, true);
    // NOTE: Area learning is necessary to achieve better precision is pose estimation
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LEARNINGMODE, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
    mTango.connect(config);
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: LEARNINGMODE and loading AREADESCRIPTION cannot be used if drift correction is enabled. (Java API Doc)

Comment: Looks like you found the answer yourself :), and yes, you can't use drift correction and learning mode together

Comment: But do you know why? Because the drift correction function recognizes known areas to replace the AR-objects. An this is pretty similiar to area learning.

Comment: It's just not a feature that implemented in Tango, if I remember correctly, there's check when you call connect to Tango, it will throw an exception if both things are enabled.